# Regex expression to find file extension in a file with multiple periods

Tags: regex

How would you write a regular expression to find the file extension of the following files, keeping in mind that what I am looking for is the ".pdf" or ".xls" portion of the string?

- REPORTPDF.20130810.pdf.pgp
- REPORTXLS.20130810.xls.pgp

**EDIT:**
The resulting filenames I want to end up with are the following:

- REPORT20130810.PDF
- REPORT20130810.XLS

I am on a Windows platform.  I've played around with this a bit at http://regexpal.com/ but so far I can only figure out how to match the date:

```
([0-9]{4}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2})
```

Comment: Tell us the output of the match that you want from those strings.

Comment: What system are you on? Windows? Linux?... Or are you doing this in a program? If so, what language?

Comment: Unless you want to change the date format i.e from 20130810 to 10082013 you don't need to recognize day month year independently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/^\(.*[^.]*\)\.[^.]*$/\1/' <<< "REPORTPDF.20130810.pdf.pgp"
REPORTPDF.20130810.pdf
```

Using `grep -P` (PCRE regex):

```
grep -oP '^.+[^.]+(?=\.[^.]+$)' <<< "REPORTPDF.20130810.pdf.pgp"
REPORTPDF.20130810.pdf
```

Comment: This is great, but still leaves in the "PDF." in the filename.  The result I was looking for was "REPORT20130810.pdf"

Comment: Both options are not giving me `PDF.`, may i know what command are you using?

Answer (score 1):

`.+\.(\w+)\.\w+$` would deliver the last but one extension as group 1, how this is accessed would then be dependent of your host language for the regex.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you :)

```
^(([A-Z a-z]*)(?:XLS.|PDF.)(\d{8})(.pdf|.xls))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/Asj5wi-CVLW7DRZj)

> ^ starts at the beginning of the string
>
> (.*) any character before
>
> \d any number 0-9
>
> {8} only 8 times for that character section (in this case 8 times of
>   the numbers 0-9)
>
> ?: is non capture groups

I wrapped the capture groups into one large one so the thing that you want will be in the first capture group :).

This can be prob be replaced

```
([A-Z a-z]*)
```

with

```
(REPORT)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the file extension to be capitalized, this should work

```
([a-zA-Z]+)\.([0-9]{4}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2})\.(xls|pdf)\.pgp
```

Matches:

```
REPORTXLS.20130810.xls.pgp
```

And then the groups you'd use are two and three

```
REPORT\2.\3
```

Matches:

```
REPORT20130810.xls
```

Problem is that you don't provide much context for how you're going about changing these file names.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what language/library you're using, but this Perl one-liner does the trick:

```
perl -lpe "s/^([^.]*)(...)\.(\d+)(\.\2)\.pgp/\1\3\4/i; $_=uc"
```

Answer (score 1):

This `(.*?(?:\..*)?)(\..*)` will hold things like:

- 'hello.1a.2bb.3' ---> group(1) == 'hello.1a.2bb', group(2) == '.3'
- 'yep.1'         ---> group(1) == 'yep', group(2) == '.1'

Answer (score 0):

If the format is pretty much fixed you could use

```
(REPORT)([^.]++)[.]([^.]++)[.]([^.]++)[.](pgp)
```

and cherry pick replacement based on what you want

Used java here but regex match would still be same

```
    String a = "REPORTPDF.20130810.pdf.pgp".replaceAll(
            "(REPORT)([^.]++)[.]([^.]++)[.]([^.]++)[.](pgp)",
            "$1--$2--$3--$4--$5");
    ;

    String b = "REPORTXLS.20130810.xls.pgp".replaceAll(
            "(REPORT)([^.]++)[.]([^.]++)[.]([^.]++)[.](pgp)",
            "$1--$2--$3--$4--$5");

    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);


REPORT--PDF--20130810--pdf--pgp
REPORT--XLS--20130810--xls--pgp
```

in your case `"$1$3.$2"`

```
    String b = "REPORTXLS.20130810.xls.pgp".replaceAll(
            "(REPORT)([^.]++)[.]([^.]++)[.]([^.]++)[.](pgp)",
            "$1$3.$2");
```

which produces intended result

```
REPORT20130810.XLS
```